# define different css for different classes in less css

Tags: css, less, mixins

I looking as an alternative as how i can **define separate css for different classes** in a same less structure, i have this..

```
.dropdown-menu, .team-contact {
    li {
        a { 
            line-height: 40px;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding-left: 40px;
            position: relative;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; display:block;
        }
    }
}
```

What i want to do is, making the `line-height` separate for both `.dropdown-menu` and `.team-contact`, i know their is no solution to have a if/else in lesscss as sass but how can i define different css for different classes defined inline...

Lets say like this:-

```
a { 
    line-height: 40px; // for .dropdown-menu
    line-height: 20px; // for .team-contact
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 40px;
    position: relative;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; display:block;
}
```

I am looking for a short solution of it if possible, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, you have to *output valid CSS*, which cannot have exactly what you describe. I think that is what Stocki was trying to get at in his answer. As far as LESS coding goes, there are at least three (or four, depending on version of LESS) different ways to do it.

**What the following code demonstrates...**

...is that there is nothing "shorter" in the *combination* of LESS input and CSS output than what #1 does in this particular use case (a deeper nesting might benefit from #3). If you are purely wanting to reduce LESS, but do not mind more CSS output (not sure I would go that way), then #2 may be the choice (assuming the generated classes do not need to be used as mixins themselves later)

### LESS 1.3.1+

---

***#1: Just repeat some code***

**LESS (19 lines)**

```
.dropdown-menu, .team-contact {
    li {
        a { 
            line-height: 40px;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding-left: 40px;
            position: relative;
            text-overflow: ellipsis; 
            display:block;
        }
    }
} 
.team-contact {
    li {
        a { 
            line-height: 20px;
        }
    }
}
```

**CSS Output (12 lines)**

.dropdown-menu li a,
.team-contact li a {
  line-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
}
.team-contact li a {
  line-height: 20px;
}

---

***#2: A mixin that defines both classes completely***

**LESS (16 lines [-3 from #1])**

```
.shareProps(@className, @lh: 40px) {
  .@{className} {
      li {
          a { 
              line-height: @lh;
              overflow: hidden;
              padding-left: 40px;
              position: relative;
              text-overflow: ellipsis; 
              display:block;
          }
      }
  }
}  
.shareProps(dropdown-menu);
.shareProps(team-contact, 20px);
```

**CSS Output (16 lines [+4 from #1])**

```
.dropdown-menu li a {
  line-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
}
.team-contact li a {
  line-height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 40px;
  position: relative;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
}
```

---

***#3: A mixin that groups for the default, then produces override***

**LESS (21 lines [+2 from #1])**

```
.shareProps(@lh: 40px, @share: 0) {
  li {
    a { 
      line-height: @lh;
      .setShare();
    }
  }
  .setShare() when (@share = true) {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 40px;
    position: relative;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    display:block;
  }
}
```

**CSS Output is *the same as #1* (12 lines)**

---

### LESS 1.4.0 (like #3 but using `extend`)

Both the number of line of LESS and the CSS Output is like #3 above.

**LESS**

```
.shareProps(@lh: 40px, @share: 0) {
  li {
    a { 
      line-height: @lh;
      .setShare();
    }
  }
  .setShare() when (@share = true) {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 40px;
    position: relative;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    display:block;
  }
}   
.dropdown-menu {
  .shareProps(40px, true);
}
.team-contact:extend(.dropdown-menu all) {
  .shareProps(20px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite an earlier defined css, so you can use:

```
.dropdown-menu li a, .team-contact li a {
    line-height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 40px;
    position: relative;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; display:block;
}
.team-contact li a {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: may be this trick is correct but if i have to do some other change to the less structure have to implement css that i want to do with less dynamically...